# Searching for a short story I read in high school

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story in high school, around 25 years ago although the story was likely much older.
It was about a man walking in the woods.

The story starts with a montage of other parts of the forest, someone else walking, a bird singing in a tree, etc...
He gets a feeling something is following him. He tries moving faster, silent, hiding. He tries climbing a tree to hide and sees something quite large pass beneath. He ends up running with said creature chasing him over a wall into a farmer's field with the unidentified creature screaming in frustration behind him. The story ends with another montage of the woods, a man's torn and bloody boot, the bird squashed against the tree, etc...
The beast obviously isn't just an animal but its true nature is only alluded to.

Anyone know what it was called by any chance?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in any more details you may remember. The only thing that looks slightly SFF-nal to me is "beast" can elaborate more on that because I'm not sure if this story is SFF-nal at the moment.